# Views whose state spans multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, slidingdrawer

How can I create a custom view whose state spans multiple Activities?  Creating a custom view is not the hard part.

To be specific, I am using a sliding drawer, and I want this drawer to maintain it's state as it appears on more than 1 activity.  I haven't seen a coded example of doing this, hoping someone else has.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on just how long it should span it. You may want to consider storing its state in the SharedPreferences - that way, it will persist even if you reset the phone.

If it's "just quick", you could pass the state data in the intent extras.

You could also consider static variables, but keep in mind that your activity could be killed off as soon as the user moves to something else, so if the user comes back, you may have lost your state.

Comment: Can I store View objects in SharedPreferences?

Comment: No. Just store the data you need to recreate the view's state.